# How do i create/save something on Desktop in openSUSE

Tags: linux, save, desktop, opensuse

So im kinda new to this. I have a new Virtual Machine openSUSE Leap, downloaded some python stuff and pgAdmin4 but i dont think it's relevant.

I've downloaded a folder that i need to be displayed on desktop. Saved it in /home/geeko/Desktop but it didn't display it. Tried to move it simply using my mouse - didn't work. Moved it by "mv" comand to root desktop - still isn't working. Tried both /usr/shared and /usr/shared/applications but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Problem. Try this: Open a Terminal and...

```
cd Desktop
ln -sfv /Path/to/your/folder NameOnDesktop
```

And then look at the Desktop what you have done.

#### PS: I am using KNOPPIX 8.6 with LXDE on a Keydrive

Comment: That is something to work with, but it still didn't work, it just created a shortcut in /root/Desktop and not on "physical" desktop.  I just want a user to see it right away when they log in

Comment: Hm, on my Desktop ( Windowmanager: LXDE ) it appears as a clickable link thats opened in filemanager. So what Windowmanager do you using? KDE? Try this: [link](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/plasma-desktop/folder-view.html)

Comment: i belive im using gnome because my default panel is on top

Comment: either i don't know how to get into folder view widget or i dont have it

Comment: OK, I am not very experienced with gnome. And using a debian based installation. Maybe you get back Desktop Icons with this tweaks [gnome desktop icon tweaks](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/re-enable-desktop-icons-in-gnome-shell/) This solution is working for my Gnome-Desktop as expected and Links and Folders are displayed in time of creation.